Does auth_request need to come before proxy_pass?
I've got a location configuration under a server block that looks like this:
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://whoami.my.domain;
        set $upstream_keepalive false;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default_location;
    }

This block is dynamically generated by nginx-proxy, a service that builds dynamic nginx configs based on discovered services.
I can provide default_location and in that file I have (along with other relevant directives for the /oauth2 location):
auth_request /oauth2/auth;

But my auth_request was ignored and nginx simply forward the request to the proxy_pass location.
My first guess was that since nginx directives are processed in order auth_request would have to go above proxy_pass, otherwise proxy_pass simply gets processed before auth_request. But later I saw examples where basic_auth directives could come after proxy_pass and I became less sure about that assumption.
Can someone confirm one way or the other whether it's required for me to place auth_request before proxy_pass or not? This is not something I can simply test because the blocks are dynamically generated in my system.

Very few directives in Nginx are ordered. IIRC these are similar directives containing regular expressions, any from the rewrite module, and allow/deny directives. So auth_request and proxy_pass can appear in either order within the same block context.
